# How to extract publicKey attribute in verifyMessageSignature method of SignatureChecker

Tags: java, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am writing and sns http end point. I have to verify the SNS message using verifyMessageSignature method of [SignatureChecker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/util/SignatureChecker.html#verifyMessageSignature%28java.lang.String,%20java.security.PublicKey%29). How can I get the publicKey attribute from message. Is there util method for it as well. Please help.

Comment: The public key is provided in a certificate, not by itself.

Comment: Is there a library or util  method which does all these from the payload ?

Answer (score 1):

The SNS message from Amazon includes a field `SigningCertURL`. Fetch the bytes at this location into a string `cert`, then make a public key from it thusly:

```
/**
 * Build a PublicKey object from a cert
 *
 * @param cert the cert body
 * @return a public key
 */
private PublicKey makePublicKey(String cert) {
    try {
        CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(stream);
        return cer.getPublicKey();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to make a public key from Amazon cert", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can call `signatureChecker.verifySignature` with it as the second argument.